# gawk to create first column based on part of second column

Tags: gawk

I have a 2 column tsv that I need to insert a new first column using part of the value in column 2.

What I have:

```
fastq/D0110.L001_R1_001.fastq  fastq/D0110.L001_R2_001.fastq
fastq/D0206.L001_R1_001.fastq  fastq/D0206.L001_R2_001.fastq
fastq/D0208.L001_R1_001.fastq  fastq/D0208.L001_R2_001.fastq
```

What I want:

```
D0110    fastq/D0110.L001_R1_001.fastq  fastq/D0110.L001_R2_001.fastq
D0206    fastq/D0206.L001_R1_001.fastq  fastq/D0206.L001_R2_001.fastq
D0208    fastq/D0208.L001_R1_001.fastq  fastq/D0208.L001_R2_001.fastq
```

I want to pull everything between "fastq/" and the first period and print that as the new first column.

Comment: You should show what code you have tried so far.

Comment: I haven't figured out how to start. I'd usually do somehting like this in R but the server that I'm using doesn't have R and this seems like something that should be very doable with gawk

Comment: When posting a question that you tag with just `gawk` it gets missed by the much wider audience who look at `awk` questions (hence you only got 1 answer to this question) so I'd suggest in future if you have a `gawk` question you also tag it with `awk` so you get a much wider pool of people who might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'[/.]' '{printf "%s\t%s\n",$2,$0}' file
D0110   fastq/D0110.L001_R1_001.fastq   fastq/D0110.L001_R2_001.fastq
D0206   fastq/D0206.L001_R1_001.fastq   fastq/D0206.L001_R2_001.fastq
D0208   fastq/D0208.L001_R1_001.fastq   fastq/D0208.L001_R2_001.fastq
```

#### How it works

awk implicitly loops over all input lines.

- `-F'[/.]'`

  This tells awk to use any occurrence of `/` or `.` as a field separator.  This means that, for your input, the string you are looking for will be the second field.
- `printf "%s\t%s\n",$2,$0`

  This tells awk to print the second field (`$2`), followed by a tab (`\t`), followed by the input line (`$0`), followed by a newline character (`\n`)

Comment: works perfect! I didn't realize you could name more than one field deliminator